# Unpermitted parameters: :team, :company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application, and I'm encountering an `Unpermitted parameters` error when trying to create a new Project. Specifically, the error mentions unpermitted parameters for `:team` and `:company`. I've defined the associations in my model and controller, but I can't seem to resolve this issue.

I've checked my `projects_controller.rb` to ensure that I'm permitting the necessary parameters, and it seems correct to me. I've also ensured that my associations in the `Project` model are set up correctly. I'm not sure why I'm still getting this error.

I expect that when I create a new Project, it should successfully save the associated `team` and `company` information. However, I'm encountering this error, and I'm not sure why.

I've tried various permutations of the parameters in my form, but none of them seem to resolve the issue. I've also checked for any typos or naming inconsistencies in my form fields.

Here is my projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  layout "dashboard"

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to(project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully created.")
    else
      render(:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to(project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully updated.")
    else
      render(:edit, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy

    redirect_to(project_url, notice: "Project was successfully destroyed")
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :estimated_completion_date, :completion_date, team_attributes: [:team_id], company_attributes: [:company_id])
  end
end`
```

Here is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @project, class: "contents") do |f| %>
  <% if project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="bg-red-50 text-red-500 px-3 py-2 font-medium rounded-lg mt-3">
      <h2><%= pluralize(project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% project.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 4, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :team do |tm_form| %>
    <div class="my-5">
      <%= tm_form.label :team_id %>
      <%= tm_form.collection_select :team_id, Team.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full appearance-none" } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :company do |tm_form| %>
    <div class="my-5">
      <%= tm_form.label :company_id %>
      <%= tm_form.collection_select :company_id, Company.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full appearance-none" } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= f.label :estimated_completion_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :estimated_completion_date, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= f.label :completion_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :completion_date, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inline">
    <%= f.submit class: "rounded-lg py-3 px-5 bg-blue-600 text-white inline-block font-medium cursor-pointer" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here is my project.rb model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :team

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :estimated_completion_date, presence: true
  validates :completion_date, presence: true
end
```

If you require access to my GitHub repo i am able to provide that, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I removed the 'rubocop' tag as this is not related to RuboCop.

Comment: Thankyou for removing that, it was my bad

Comment: look at log/development.log and find what parameters are being submitted to the controller. You'll see a `:team` parameter and a `:company' parameter. But you have not permitted those parameters in `project_params`. That's why you're seeing the error.

Comment: you don't need `fields_for` here, because `team_id` is an attribute of `Project` model: `f.collection_select :team_id, Team.order(:name) ...`. same for company.

Comment: @LesNightingill this is the error i am getting
`Unpermitted parameters: :team, :company. Context: { controller: ProjectsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x000000010f1567c8>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "project"=>{"name"=>"Ellis Brookes", "description"=>"meow", "team"=>{"team_id"=>"1"}, "company"=>{"company_id"=>"1"}, "estimated_completion_date"=>"2023-09-17", "completion_date"=>"2023-09-24"}, "commit"=>"Create Project", "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"create"} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing simple assignment and nested attributes.

You don't need or want to use `fields_for` when you're just selecting an existing record:

```
<%= form_with(model: @project, class: "contents") do |f| %>

  ...

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= tm_form.label :team_id %>
    <%= tm_form.collection_select :team_id, Team.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full appearance-none" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :company_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select :company_id, Company.order(:name), :id, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full appearance-none" } %>
  </div>

  # ...

<% end %>
```

All you actually need to do is pass an id of the record. `fields_for` is used to pass nested hashes (and arrays of hashes).

You're also whitelisting the wrong attributes:

```
  def project_params
    params.require(:project)
          .permit(
             :name, :description, 
             :estimated_completion_date, :completion_date,
             :team_id, :company_id
          )
  end
```

Both team_id and company_id are just simple scalar values (strings).

Comment: Ok i have changed that now i am getting the error `nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path`

Comment: You're missing `before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`.

Comment: thankyou that has seemed to have worked